# CollectionView cells inconsistently showing checkbox when entering editing mode

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm facing an issue with my UICollectionView when entering editing mode. The problem is that when I scroll down, some cells appear with checkboxes, while others don't. However, I want all cells to consistently show checkboxes when in editing mode.

**Additional Context:**

- I'm using a custom layout for my UICollectionView.
- I've implemented custom cells (MailListCell in this case).
- The issue occurs when I scroll down the collection view while in editing mode.

**Expected Behavior:**
All cells in the collection view should consistently show checkboxes when in editing mode, regardless of whether they are visible or not.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        
        if editing {
            // Enable multi-selection, show checkboxes, etc.
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelEditing))
            
            //shift the list to right
//            collectionViewLeadingConstraint?.constant = 50
            
            // Show the checkboxes and move labels to right
                    for indexPath in mailListCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                        if let cell = mailListCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MailListCell {
                            cell.moveLabelsToRight()
//                            cell.roundCheckbox.isHidden = false
//                            cell.animateCheckboxAppearance()
                        }
                    }
            mailListCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        } else {
            // Disable multi-selection, hide checkboxes, etc.
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
            
            //bring the list back to original position
//            collectionViewLeadingConstraint?.constant = 0
            
                    for indexPath in mailListCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                        if let cell = mailListCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MailListCell {
                            cell.moveLabelsToOriginalPosition()
//                            cell.roundCheckbox.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
        }
        
        // need to call layoutIfNeeded to apply the constraint changes
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    }
    @objc func cancelEditing() {
        // Implement any logic needed when the user cancels the editing mode.
        // For example, deselect any selected cells, hide checkboxes, etc.
        
        setEditing(false, animated: true)
        mailListCollectionView.allowsSelection = false
    }
```

below are the functions that bring about changes on screen when entering and exiting editing mode.

```
extension MailListCell {
    func moveLabelsToRight() {
        senderLeadingConstraint?.constant = 50
        subjectLeadingConstraint?.constant = 50
        dateLeadingConstraint?.constant = 50
        separatorLeadingConstraint?.constant = 50
        roundCheckboxLeadingConstraint?.constant = 10
        
        // Change alpha value to create a fading effect
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    self.roundCheckbox.alpha = 1
                }, completion: nil)
    }

    func moveLabelsToOriginalPosition() {
        senderLeadingConstraint?.constant = 16
        subjectLeadingConstraint?.constant = 16
        dateLeadingConstraint?.constant = 16
        separatorLeadingConstraint?.constant = 16
        roundCheckboxLeadingConstraint?.constant = -20
        
        // Change alpha value to create a fading effect
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    self.roundCheckbox.alpha = 0
                }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to ensure consistent checkbox visibility during editing mode would be greatly appreciated.

Updated code:

```
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        
        if editing {
            isEditingMode = true
            // Enable multi-selection, show checkboxes, etc.
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelEditing))
            
            //shift the list to right
//            collectionViewLeadingConstraint?.constant = 50
            
            // Show the checkboxes and move labels to right
                    for indexPath in mailListCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                        if let cell = mailListCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MailListCell {
                            cell.moveLabelsToRight()
//                            cell.roundCheckbox.isHidden = false
//                            cell.animateCheckboxAppearance()
                        }
                    }
            mailListCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        } else {
            isEditingMode = false
            // Disable multi-selection, hide checkboxes, etc.
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
            
            //bring the list back to original position
//            collectionViewLeadingConstraint?.constant = 0
            
                    for indexPath in mailListCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                        if let cell = mailListCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MailListCell {
                            cell.moveLabelsToOriginalPosition()
//                            cell.roundCheckbox.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
        }
        
        // need to call layoutIfNeeded to apply the constraint changes
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MailListCell
        
        if isEditingMode {
                cell.moveLabelsToRight()
            } else {
                cell.moveLabelsToOriginalPosition()
            }
        
        cell.senderLabel.text = "some sender"
        cell.subjectLabel.text = "some subject"
        cell.dateLabel.text = "dd/mm/yyyy"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Check your `cellForItem` code. It needs to set the cell correctly when cels are reused.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the `cellForItem` datasource as @Paulw11 said in his comment. I assume you will have a function to enable editing mode, such as:

```swift
func startEditing() {
    ...
    isEditingMode = true
    mailListCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    mailListCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Then in `cellForItem` function:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = ... as! MailListCell
    if isEditingMode {
        cell.moveLabelsToRight()
    } else {
        cell.moveLabelsToOriginalPosition()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I implemented as per the suggested solution. I noticed a new issue  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1veLaGSuXT9_Ta-tViTyjfHturjzkdJpp/view?usp=share_link) 
I've added the updated code in the question above.

Comment: Also, remove `cell.removeLabel...` from  `setEditing` function too. Handle toolbar action in another method instead of overriding setEditing.